# how to update uitableview in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

I've `UItableView` in `UIViewController` and database connected to `UItableVIew` it loads data from `sqlite3` database but its not Showing new content when i add new content to database until i relaunch the application. I tried below code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.LengthTableFrom reloadData];
}
```

Comment: [yourtableview reloadData]; whenever you are getting the data from the Database into array. that time just put this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you add new content at that after that get all data again and also add this line after get all data

```
[self.LengthTableFrom reloadData]
```

i hope it will work fine..

:)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are adding or editing your data to database.

And in viewController where tableView exist

In `viewDidLoad` you are fetching data from database & saving into array. Reloading list in `viewWillAppear`. For fist time it works fine, after when you add new content to your database your array for tableView will not be having new content.

For testing you can have your data fetching from database in your `viewWillAppear` view controller, to check it works fine.

In real time you have to add the new content to database get the ref id, and add the new content with ref id to your array for tableView.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply mean that you are not calling the  `[self.LengthTableFrom reloadData]` method properly.
You should place this code   `[self.LengthTableFrom reloadData]` just below the code where you fetching the database content .

i hope it'll work fine.